# Oracle SQL escape character (for a '&')

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping, oracle-sqldeveloper

While attempting to execute SQL insert statements using [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) I keep generating an "Enter substitution value" prompt:

```
insert into agregadores_agregadores 
(
 idagregador,
 nombre,
 url
) 
values 
(
 2,
 'Netvibes',
 'http://www.netvibes.com/subscribe.php?type=rss\&amp;url='
);
```

I've tried [escaping the special character in the query](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm) using the '\' above but I still can't avoid the ampersand, '&', causing a string substitution.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

the `&` is the default value for `DEFINE`, which allows you to use substitution variables.  I like to turn it off using

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

then you won't have to worry about escaping or CHR(38).

Answer (score 75):

`|| chr(38) ||`

This solution is perfect.

Comment: This gets the job done, but is a little clunky when dealing with pre-existing strings.

Comment: For me SET DEFINE OFF did not work. Your solution worked will. Thank you...

Comment: Where can I find a complete list of chr() characters? I have a similar problem but in my case I'm looking to escape a  ( ' )  character.

Comment: @user7587050 You can use any ASCII table. They are readily available on the Internet, e.g. on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 33):

Set the define character to something other than &

```
SET DEFINE ~
create table blah (x varchar(20));
insert into blah (x) values ('blah&amp');
select * from blah;

X                    
-------------------- 
blah&amp
```

Answer (score 17):

```
insert into AGREGADORES_AGREGADORES (IDAGREGADOR,NOMBRE,URL)
values (2,'Netvibes',
'http://www.netvibes.com/subscribe.php?type=rss' || chr(38) || 'amp;url=');
```

Comment: This is a much better general solution that is independent of user priveleges (i.e. when users are not allowed to SET DEFINE OFF) and for when users want to specify both ampersands in text and defined variables in the same SQL command.

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT 'Free &' || ' Clear' FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 7):

`select 'one'||'&'||'two' from dual`

Comment: The ampersand need only be at the end of the string, saving half the concatenation. `select 'one&' || 'two' from dual`

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is you need to set the escape character to '\':
SET ESCAPE ON

The problem may have occurred either because escaping was disabled, or the escape character was set to something other than '\'.  The above statement will enable escaping *and* set it to '\'.

---

None of the other answers previously posted actually answer the original question.  They all work around the problem but don't resolve it.

Comment: I read on Ask Tom (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1629001802771) that "SET ESCAPE is a sqplus'ism". So this would only be the real answer if the question were about SQL*Plus.

Comment: @KarlKieninger: For the most part, you're right. But the whole idea of a substitution variable is *also* an sqlplus-ism.  Since SQL Developer is recognizing &amp; as a substitution variable (which is one sqlplus-ism) I guess I'm not surprised it might also recognizing the SET ESCAPE command (another sqlplus-ism).  According to the SQL Developer User Guide, its "Script Runner" does recognize a limited set of SQL*Plus features, including substitution vars (at least vers. 19). However, it gave error messages when I tried SET ESCAPE. But it did accept SET DEFINE OFF. Curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 0):

add this before your request

```
set define off;
```