# Escape ampersand in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, escaping, special-characters, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying a simple INSERT statement against an Oracle database.  One of the values is a VARCHAR2 field and the insert statement contains an ampersand.  How do I do this?  I've tried the following methods:

1. Escape the & as \& with set escape on
2. set scan off (this causes an ORA-00922 missing or invalid option error)
3. set define off (this causes an ORA-00922 missing or invalid option error)

Any other ideas?

Comment: I've "solved" it using the chr(38) solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a but would like something more graceful.

Comment: Are you trying to execute the insert via a SQL window or a command window?

Comment: Ray, have you tried setting the define to another character rather than just setting it off entirely? Not sure if it would help as I don't use PLSQL Developer but it might...

Comment: SQL window. This is especially important as our deployment team (for good or bad) follows this procedure too.

Comment: @Ollie, yes I did. same result.

Comment: Only the Command window emulates the SQL*Plus `set` variables, hence the syntax errors in your SQL window. Also there is no 'escape' character in SQL (or in PL/SQL Developer) except as part of a `like` expression, which is why your \ isn't recognised.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How I solved it is escaping the & with another &.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) VALUES ('Up && Away');
```

Works nicely. Thanks for all the help

Comment: indeed, but be careful not to replace "&" by "&&" with plsqld native search and replace tool, as it might enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Not for me... my solution was  the answer "...INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('Sid ' || '&' || ' Nancy');..."

Answer (score 33):

At the bottom of a SQL window there is a button to disable/enable substitution variables:

[image]

Comment: That was hard to find. I spent 10 minutes browsing through all the options in settings and only then found this online.

Comment: This answer works in SQLTools as well.

Answer (score 13):

One of the features of PL/SQL Developer which it takes time to get familiar with is the plethora of different window types.

One of these is the COMMAND window, which is basically a SQL*Plus emulator.  We can run SQL*Plus commands as well as SQL, so `SET ESCAPE`, `SET DEFINE`  and indeed `SET SCAN OFF` work in that window.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried something like this?

```
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('Sid ' || '&' || ' Nancy');
```

Improving my first answer, your problem is related with PL/SQL Developer. If you execute your block in a PL/SQL Developer Command window, you could also use the standard SET DEFINE OFF, which works the same as in SQL*Plus.

Comment: I don't think that is any more graceful than the `chr(38)` solution Ray mentions.

Comment: propably, but it's the one that I used when I faced a similar problem a year ago. In http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ there are some nice solutions too in SQL*Plus, like SET ESCAPE '\', SET DEFINE ~ or SET SCAN OFF

Comment: Nice solution and more pleasant than fiddling with global settings. A little shorter: 'Sid &' || ' Nancy' .

Answer (score 5):

the concat worked perfectly fine for me below is what i did in my select statement:

```
select FUND_NM
FROM PERFORMANCE
WHERE upper(FUND_DESC) in ('My L&' ||'L FUNDS')
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `chr(38)` where I need an ampersand in PL/SQL.

```
addr:= 'mysite.com/order.aspx?no=5678' || CHR(38) || 'id=947';
--above line gives you 'mysite.com/order.aspx?no=5678&id=947';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a SQL Editor issue. To resolve this just compile the procedure with SET DEFINE OFF; .
Execution which is PL (executing in server) will not face this issue.