# & IN WHERE CLAUSE of oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I had SQL query running on SQL developer IDE:

```
SELECT IC.ID 
FROM INSTITUTE_COURSE IC 
WHERE IC.NAME = 'CIVIL & ARCHITECTURE CAD';
```

Due to `&` in where clause, ide returns an error `"Enter Substitution Variable".`

If I remove `&` in String, query runs fine.

**My Question is how to run query with &/ampersand in where clause?**

Comment: I tried a similar query (WHERE clause with a string contaning an &) into PL/SQL Developer and I didn't have this behavior.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus, & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute the command `SET DEFINE OFF` before executing your query.

Comment: actually this answer is better understood when the OP question has been tagged “sqlplus”

Comment: @Benoit -- not sure what you mean.  The command works in SQL Developer as well (I tested it before posting).

Comment: SQL Developer is a tool that conforms to the SQL*Plus syntax as well for scripts to be portable. But '&' in a SQL query is correct if you program in C++ or use Tora or other oracle clients.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Dave Costa's answer, here are the relevant parts of the manual:

Substitution Variables:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch5.htm#CACIFHGB

The SET DEFINE OFF command:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch8.htm#sthref929

Comment: Just FYI, these links are specifically about SQLPlus, but in this case the information applies to SQL Developer as well.

Comment: @Dave: good point. But then the SQL Developer manuals simply mentions "SQL*Plus commands supported" but does not explain them, so apparently they work the same as in SQL*Plus