# Escaping & in perl DB queries

Tags: perl, oracle

I need to manipulate some records in a DB and write their values to another table. Some of these values have an '&' in the string, i.e. 'Me & You'. Short of finding all of these values and placing a \ before any &'s, how can insert these values into a table w/o oracle choking on the &?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-

Comment: If you are using DBI, then use bind_param() to quote the values into the table. (I assume you are building a string query and passing it wholesale to prepare/execute ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use placeholders.  Instead of putting `'$who'` in your SQL statement, prepare with a ? there instead, and then either bind $who, or execute with $who as the appropriate argument.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached('INSERT INTO FOO (WHO) VALUES (?)');
$sth->bind_param(1, $who);
my $rc = $sth->execute();
```

This is safer and faster than trying to do it yourself.  (There is a "quote" method in DBI, but this is better than that.)

Comment: My single favorite feature of Oracle is named placeholders: `my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached('INSERT INTO FOO (WHO) VALUES (:who)');` `$sth->bind_param(':who', $who);` This reduces SQL portability, but if your already tied tightly to Oracle it can vastly improve maintainability.

Answer (score 8):

This is definitely a wheel you don't need to reinvent. If you are using [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI), don't escape the input; use placeholders.

Example:

```
my $string = "database 'text' with &special& %characters%";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE some_table SET some_column=?
                         WHERE some_other_column=42");
$sth->execute($string);
```

The [`DBD::Oracle`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aOracle) module (and all the other `DBD::xxxxx` modules) have undergone extensive testing and real world use. Let it worry about how to get your text inserted into the database.