# How to enter special characters like “§” in oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, special-characters

I want to insert special character `§` in my `INSERT` statement.

My insert is:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, class_id) VALUES ('Samantha', 'Java_22 & Oracle_14');
```

If I try to run this query than am getting popup and it ask me to enter value for Oracle_14, so my question is how can I enter special characters like `§` in the `INSERT` statement for oracle db ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle pl-sql escape character (for a '&')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a)

Comment: If you are using SQL*Plus to perform the insert, then you need to **SET DEFINE OFF**, as by default the & character is used to indicate a substitution variable in SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 3):

The '&' character is the default macro definition character is SQL*Plus.  If you're using SQL*Plus to execute your queries there are two ways to work around this:

1. Use the `SET DEFINE OFF` command to turn off macro definition altogether, or
2. Use `SET DEFINE <some_other_character>` to change the macro definition character; e.g. you could issue `SET DEFINE ^` to change the macro definition character to '^' for the duration of  your current session.

The other option I can think of would be to use the `CHR` function to avoid the need to type in a `&` character.  CHR(38) is the equivalent of the `&` character, so if you used

```
'Java_22 ' || CHR(38) || ' Oracle_14'
```

you'd get the same result with no `&` in there to be misinterpreted by SQL*Plus.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Java_22 '||'&'||' Oracle_14'