# PL/SQL CONCAT Function

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Goal: Have an Excel document that links to customer bills.

Desired PL/SQL output:

```
account_id | bill_id | '=HYPERLINK(".\"&'||bill_id||'&"-00.PDF")'
-----------+---------+----------
12345      | 10      | =HYPERLINK(".\"&10&"-00.PDF")
23456      | 11      | =HYPERLINK(".\"&11&"-00.PDF")
34567      | 12      | =HYPERLINK(".\"&12&"-00.PDF")
```

PL/SQL queries that ([documentation here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php)) are not picking up the second concat and PL/SQL Developer generates a popup with title "Variables" asking for a value.
`Select account_id, bill_id,  '=HYPERLINK(".\"&' || bill_id || '&"-00.PDF")' from customer_table`
Also tested
`Select account_id, bill_id,  CONCAT( CONCAT('=HYPERLINK(".\"&',bill_id),'&"-00.PDF")') from customer_table`

Current output:

```
account_id | bill_id | '=HYPERLINK(".\"&'||bill_id||'&"-00.PDF")'
-----------+---------+----------
12345      | 10      | =HYPERLINK(".\"&10)
23456      | 11      | =HYPERLINK(".\"&11)
34567      | 12      | =HYPERLINK(".\"&12)
```

I havn't seen this particular issue in my searches but will update if I find a solution. Would anyone see an issue with this or be able to propose a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` i.e. Ampersand is considered as a substitution operator in **`SQL*Plus`**. Well, having said that, most of the **GUI based client tools** are capable of executing the SQL*Plus commands.

Your client tool is considering `&` as a substitution operator.

You could **ESCAPE** it.

Or, `set define off` at session level.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT 'HYPERLINK(".\"&10&"-00.PDF")' FROM dual;
Enter value for 10:
old   1: SELECT 'HYPERLINK(".\"&10&"-00.PDF")' FROM dual
new   1: SELECT 'HYPERLINK(".\"&"-00.PDF")' FROM dual

'HYPERLINK(".\"&"-00.PDF"
-------------------------
HYPERLINK(".\"&"-00.PDF")

SQL> SET DEFINE OFF
SQL> SELECT 'HYPERLINK(".\"&10&"-00.PDF")' FROM dual;

'HYPERLINK(".\"&10&"-00.PDF"
----------------------------
HYPERLINK(".\"&10&"-00.PDF")

SQL>
```

Comment: I was just looking at the same conclusion ([post][1]). Took me actually reading through the question to see the ampersand might be the issue.

Thanks a million for your input.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a

Comment: @user3240704 Ampersand is the issue, try `set define off` and then retry. Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:-

```
SELECT account_id, bill_id, CONCAT('=HYPERLINK(".\"&',bill_id,'&"-00.PDF")') 
FROM customer_table;
```