# Handle ' and & in SUBSTR Function

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have been asked to split comments field to 75 chars each and when I used substr function in a procedure to split all the comments, Comments having ' and & symbols are encountering exceptions.

Any help to split the data without any data loss is highly appreciated.

Sample data : Health Provider indicated in error that the employee DNA&d. The DNA charge has been removed.

Expected O/P: Health Provider indicated in error that the employee DNA&d. The DNA charge

Comment: show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: One of a sample is ----Health Provider indicated in error that the employee DNA&d.The DNA charge has been removed------- and the expected O/P is ----Health Provider indicated in error that the employee DNA&d. The DNA charge------

Comment: Edit your question and show your query and sample data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle pl-sql escape character (for a '&')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'Health Provider indicated in error that the employee DNA&d. The DNA charge has been removed.'
  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apostrophe '' in this string'
  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR( value, 1, 75 ) AS substr
FROM   DATA;
```

**Ouput**:

```
SUBSTR                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Health Provider indicated in error that the employee DNA&d. The DNA charge  
Apostrophe ' in this string
```

Comment: Sorry, how can i incorporate the same in plsql stored procedure? Still those rows were skipped when i add set define off before executing the procedure?