# Using '&' in a where clause

Tags: where-clause, plsqldeveloper

Executing the code in SQL Developer. It seems to take the '&' as an input command rather than a character. Is there a way around this guys. Thanks in Advance :)

`Select * from table1 where column1 = 'M & S Simply Food`;

Sorry just adding up to my question, If i did this

A.Store Name contains : M & S Simply Food, Burberry,World Duty Free Pandora.

B. Store Name Contains : (M & S Simply Food, Burberry) in a single row how would should i format the content of the cell for table B. Store name so it can do a match with A.store name in regards to the following code

`Select A.* from table1 A join table2 B 
  on A.id = B.id 
   where ( INSTR (',' || UPPER(B.STORE_NAME) || ',', ',' || UPPER(A.COMPANY_NAME) || ',') 
    <> 0 
     OR 
      UPPER(B.STORE_NAME) IS NULL)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle pl-sql escape character (for a '&')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a)

Comment: You should add any additional information **to the question**, not in comments.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter link description here][1]

@Matt Jones
  [1]: [Oracle pl-sql escape character (for a '&')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137354/oracle-pl-sql-escape-character-for-a) seems to work good for me. using it 'M & S Simply Food, Burberry' like that in the IN clause seems to work fine as well

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the other ' in your statement

Yours:

```
Select * from table1 where column1 = 'M & S Simply Food
```

And this is how it should be:

```
Select * from table1 where column1 = 'M & S Simply Food'
```

Then the '&' should be handled as a letter from the String.